# Stop sharing node's geometry with its clone programmatically

Tags: swift, scenekit

When you create a copy of an object, geometry and its properties (materials...) are shared with that object.
In Xcode Scene Editor you can easily disable that by setting `Geometry Sharing` (under `Attributes Inspector`) to `Unshare`.

I want to achieve the same thing programmatically, but can't find any similar properties in `SceneKit` documentation.
I have found a similar post where someone proposed copying the object, its geometry and its material. I tried doing so but had no success.

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
let randomColors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.blue,  UIColor.red,  UIColor.yellow,  UIColor.gray]
let obstacleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Scenes/obstacleNormal.scn")
let obstacle = obstacleScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "obstacle", recursively: true)

for i in 1...15 {
    let randomPosition = SCNVector3(x: Float(i) * 3.5, y: 0.15, z: sign * Float(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Int(playgroundZ/2 - 2.0))) + 1))
    let randomColor = randomColors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))]

    let obstacleCopy = obstacle?.clone()
    obstacleCopy?.position = randomPosition
    obstacleCopy?.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = randomColor
    obstacleCopy?.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 10.0 * Float(i), y: Float(30 - i), z: 5.0 * Float(i) * sign) //malo na random

    obstacleCopy?.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
    obstacleCopy?.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
    obstacleCopy?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.obstacle
    obstacleCopy?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none
    obstacleCopy?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.car1 | PhysicsCategory.car2 | PhysicsCategory.barrier

    obstacleArray.append(obstacleCopy!)
    raceScene!.rootNode.addChildNode(obstacleCopy!)
}
```

I want to set different attributes on those objects but can't, because their geometry is shared.
I tried doing this with copying the object and cloning it, but I couldn't see any differences with copying or cloning it.

Is there a property which you can use to achieve geometry unsharing, similar to the option in the Scene Editor, **OR** should the method of also copying object's geometry and its materials work?

Comment: I'm no expert, but this looks like something where the creation of instances instead of clones might help. But I could be way wrong on that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the `clone()` [API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1408046-clone), you can copy the geometry after cloning, this will create a new unshared geometry for your node.

```
let newNode = node.clone()
newNode.geometry = node.geometry?.copy() as? SCNGeometry
```

The material attached to the copied geometry is still the same one being used on the original, so any changes will still affect both.
Either create a new material, or make a copy.

```
if let newMaterial = newNode.geometry?.materials.first.copy() as? SCNMaterial {
    //make changes to material
    newNode.geometry?.materials = [newMaterial]
}
```

Comment: I did find this information but unfortunately adding the second line after creating the clone has no effect on nodes. Apparently I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Comment: That's because your material is still shared by both geometries, you can copy that too, or make a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You could deep clone a `SCNNode`, which creates an unshared geometry and unshared materials with the original.

```
fileprivate func deepCopyNode(node: SCNNode) -> SCNNode {
    let clone = node.clone()
    clone.geometry = node.geometry?.copy() as? SCNGeometry
    if let g = node.geometry {
        clone.geometry?.materials = g.materials.map{ $0.copy() as! SCNMaterial }
    }
    return clone
}
```